# Delphi MySql: Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, delphi

I'm using Delphi to perform a query on MySQL database.

A simple query like:

```
select * from table1, table2 
where table1.field1 = table2.field1
```

works perfectly via Navicat, but fails using delphi with error message:

"Unknown column field1 in where clause"

Thanks

Comment: try with aliases means first give aliases to tables and then use aliases in place of full table name...even both are same but you can try.

Comment: So note that Navicat's behaviour is not standard and you'd better un-learn that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use joins and aliases :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
 FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
```